# Change AWS EC2 instance aws_access_key_id & aws_secret_access_key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

We have an AWS EC2 instance, where someone has removed the `USER CREDIANTIALS`.
So when we run the `.aws/credentials` we get a `aws_access_key_id` & `aws_secret_access_key` which doesn't exists anymore.

```
ubuntu@prod-ip-000:~$ cat .aws/credentials
[default]
aws_access_key_id = AKIASIY3TRVDD7QZXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = f7rA1eebxzdd61yP4vPTNql09FxgZZam/V5HxxXx
```

Now I have created another user and add their `aws_access_key_id` & `aws_secret_access_key` on the server by

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIASIY3TRVDCDXXXXXX
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=cgGjUlh5FDPLpUVBBK5Rl8jlWKV6Iv4NrXXXXXX
```

After that when I run `cat .aws/credentials` again it still show me the previous user crediantials.

```
ubuntu@prod-ip-000:~$ cat .aws/credentials
[default]
aws_access_key_id = AKIASIY3TRVDD7QZXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = f7rA1eebxzdd61yP4vPTNql09FxgZZam/V5HxxXx
```

Does anyone know how can I change the Crediantials of the Old one with the new user's credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the .aws/credetials file and use vim or nano to edit the file and replace the older credentials with your new credentials it will work.